# UIVisualEffectFilterView cover UINavigationBarBackground

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationbar

I just start learning ios, using swift 3.

When I set NavigationBar's BackgroundColor, I see some layers cover it. So the result is not what I expected.

I set NavigationBar's BackgroundColor by this (in AppDelegate)

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 149/255, blue: 135/255, alpha: 1.0)
```

This is my result (navigation bar's background color is wrong)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0PuV.png)

This is Debug View
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJKP5.png)

**How can I remove layers that cover navigation bar background? Or set color for it?** Thank you all!

Comment: use `navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red` on your ViewController class

Comment: This help!!! Thank you a lot.